# 12.04 Hauppauge HDP VR LIRC Repeating keys

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I have searched and read for months, every article I can find on this subject. 
All seems correct, only button presses from the remote repeat 2-4 times while controlling MythTV. I have tried repeat=0 and repeat=3 in .lircrc with no changes.
It is as if .lircrc is being ignored.

The HD-PVR works. Shows up as: Bus 002 Device 006: ID 2040:4902 Hauppauge HD PVR.

These modules Are loaded:

ir_lirc_codec          12859  0

rc_core                26412  8 ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,ir_kbd_i2c

lirc_zilog             22513  2

lirc_dev               19204  2 ir_lirc_codec,lirc_zilog

THis all worked perfectly before upgrading to 12.04.

Any ideas will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried as you did to edit `.lircrc`, then found there was more than one instance of `irexec` running which caused each button to repeat. Use

```
ps -ef
```

to see what's running. I had added `irexec` to the startup menu based some LIRC docs I was using, but `mythv` did this already, I think after selecting the IR remote in the initial `mythtv` setup.  Removed the `irexec` from the startup menu and problem solved.